# How to listen for clicks outside a child component?

Tags: angular

I need to know if it is being clicked outside the CHILD COMPONENT, so I can close it.

I can't use mosueover any of that.

I'm using Hostlistenner, but in the target it always sees the parent of the element and never the child.

```
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  public onClick(target) {
    console.log(target)
  }

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {}
```

An example of what happens is the following, I have the following structure:

```
<componentA>
  <componentB />
</componentA>
```

I want to know if the click is being made outside of componentB, but with the code above, it is only listening to componentA.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK The only good solution would be to use a parent `div` set in absolute position and a relative child with an higher `z-index` than the parent and attach a `click` event on the parent to close whatever needs to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that in addition to being getting the parent component and not the child, in production the `document` was giving undefined, so to correct both, the following code was used:

```
import { Inject, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

this.isOpened: boolean = false;

constructor(
 @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document,
 private _elementRef: ElementRef
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
 this._handleOnDocumentClick();
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
 this.removeEventListener('click', this._handleOnDocumentClick, true)
}

private _handleOnDocumentClick(): void {
 this._document.addEventListener('click', (event: Event) => {
   event.composedPath().includes(this._elementRef.nativeElement)
     ? this.isOpened = !this.isOpened
     : this.isOpened = false;
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitely check for the clicked DOM element, because listening to click on `document` will always treat the click as targetting the document as a whole (which is rather obvious). So you need to import `ElementRef` into child component and use it to check if the child is the actual target of the click:

```
 import { HostListener } from '@angular/core'; // and other modules from /core
 
 (...)

 constructor(private elem: ElementRef) {}

 @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
 docClicked(event: Event) {
    if (this.elem.nativeElement.contains(event.target))
       console.log('clicked inside');
    else {
       console.log('clicked outside');
    }
 }
```

Then you can do what you want in the docClicked/else block.

Check [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-urtm6r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts) for emitting to parent method that will set to false the var that controls the display of the child component in the parent template.

Comment: Exactly, I had already tried this, what happens is that EVENT.TARGET is equal to the PARENT ELEMENT and NATIVE ELEMENT is equal to the CHILD ELEMENT, it never falls "inside". I updated my question with the images.

Comment: Is your HostListener in parent or child component?

Comment: Child Component

Comment: Did you actually use `target` or `event` as argument in the handler method?

Comment: I'm using exactly your code.

Comment: Can you create a sample stackblitz project?

Comment: I can not because it is internal code, what you can do to simulate is simply the following, create three components (A,B,C), the C component is a select custom and it is inside the B component (it is a container practically), and the B component is inside the A component.